# BitTorrent Sync log parsing using Python

Tags: python, bittorrent-sync

I'm trying to parse the debug log created by BitTorrent Sync using Python. The sample log I'm working on is quite large (~10 MB), so if someone wants to take a look see here: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/01a0ae7c (7z compressed; don't use their downloader)

I want to create a CSV file which includes the filename, start time & end time (of receiving), no of chunks, average time & transfer speed etc.

I'm getting my ideas from Python Docs... being a noob, it'll take some time.

Examples from the log:

```
[20141006 12:10:42.290] SyncFilesController: Got file from remote (192.168.3.13:41740): AUD_30_3822029472_1442025768_20140923053708.out state: 1 type: file total:801 have:801 t:1412577403 mt:1412577403 7842B73B340FD81AB3B426CBB0822FE68FF156B7
[20141006 12:10:43.684] /home/de/Desktop/Sync_test/AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out: Piece 3 complete
[20141006 12:11:03.951] Finished downloading file AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out, writing file attributes mt:1412577397
```

My first approach:

```
log=open("sync_de.log",'r');
fn=open("fn.log",'w');
st=open("st.log",'w');
et=open("et.log",'w');

for eachline in log:
    if 'Got file from remote' in eachline:
        fn.write(str(eachline[88:135]) + '\n')

    elif 'event = "IN_CREATE"' in eachline:
        st.write(str(eachline[43:90] + ': ' + eachline[10:22]) + '\n')

    elif 'Finished downloading file' in eachline:
        et.write(str(eachline[50:97] + ': ' + eachline[10:22]) + '\n')
```

How do I combine these data without storing them in individual files?? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tito

many options. One of them:

create a list, parse the lines (the way you are doing is ok), put the info as a list into the list.
Output all with csv module.

Ex:

```
import csv
log=open("sync_de.log",'r')
out=open("fn.csv",'w')
csv = csv.writer(out)

#  to store the list
out_list = []

for eachline in log:
   # your code
   if blabla:
      out_list.append([filename, start, end])

# write the csv
csv.writerows(out_list)
```

for more options, check the csv module
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Oh, and 10mb is piece of cake to python. You can load easily 4gb, 10gb files, depending on your ram.

Comment: Thanks! It looks promising, but the problem is the 'if' condition is dynamic i.e if 'Got file from remote' in eachline is true then eachline[88:135] gives the file name whereas 'event = "IN_CREATE"' in eachline is true then eachline[10:22] gives the starting time, though those 2 'eachline's may be different.

Comment: The 'in' will find it inside the string, independent of where it is. You may try regex. That's the most powerful stuff. It will blow your mind...

Answer (score 0):

Lets take another approach. A snippet of of fn_c.log (file names & no of chunks):

```
AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out: 801
AUD_30_3822029472_1442025768_20140923053708.out: 801
AUD_59_3579916998_7069213690_20130110135656.out: 801
```

st.log (starting times after sorting):

```
AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out: 12:10:43.117
AUD_30_3822029472_1442025768_20140923053708.out: 12:11:03.951
AUD_59_3579916998_7069213690_20130110135656.out: 12:12:10.933
```

et.log (ending times after sorting):

```
AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out: 12:11:03.951
AUD_30_3822029472_1442025768_20140923053708.out: 12:12:10.933
AUD_59_3579916998_7069213690_20130110135656.out: 12:12:34.120
```

and so on. Now how can I combine them so that:

```
1st column: File name
2nd column: No of chunks
3rd column: Start time
```

etc.??

Basically I plan to read a file where only filenames are stored & then pick up corresponding values from different files, like:

```
file = open("fn.log",'r');
log=open("sync_de.log",'r');
cr = open("cr.log",'w');
line = file.readline()

for u in line.split():
    for eachline in log:
        if 'event = "IN_CREATE"' in eachline and u in eachline:
            cr.write(str(u + ',' + eachline[10:22]) + '\n')
```

But only first one is written:

```
AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out,12:10:43.117
```

Comment: use a dictionary and the key as the index:
begin = {}
end = {}
begin['filename'] = time
end['filename'] = end_time

in the end
for key in begin.keys(): # for all the files as the keys
   write(key, begin[key], end[key])

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have managed to get it done in a very crude way.

```
import os,math
from datetime import *

thor = raw_input("Enter the name of the BitTorrent Sync debug log file: ")
odin = raw_input("Enter the name of the folder where synced files are stored: ")

report = open("report.log",'w'); 
sync_log = open(thor,'r');
fn = open("fn.log",'w');
pre_st = open("pre_st.log",'w');
pre_et = open("pre_et.log",'w');

report.write('Name of the files & corresponding no of chunks' + '\n')
report.write('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' + '\n')

i=0
for eachline in sync_log:
    if 'Got file from remote' in eachline:
        i=i+1
        fn.write(str(eachline[88:135]) + ' ' + str(eachline[162:165]) + '\n')
        report.write(str(eachline[88:135]) + ' ' + str(eachline[162:165]) + '\n')
    elif 'event = "IN_CREATE"' in eachline:
        pre_st.write(str(eachline[43:90] + ' ' + eachline[10:22]) + '\n')
    elif 'Finished downloading file' in eachline:
        pre_et.write(str(eachline[50:97] + ' ' + eachline[10:22]) + '\n')
report.write('\n')

report.write('Total no of files' + '\n')
report.write('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' + '\n')
report.write(str(i) + '\n' + '\n')

report.write('Size of the files (in bytes)' + '\n')
report.write('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' + '\n')
dir = odin
fs = open("fs.log",'w');
for f in os.listdir(dir):
    if os.path.isfile(dir + '/' + f) and len(f) == 47:
        fs.write(str(os.path.getsize(dir + '/' + f)) + '\n')
        report.write(f + ' ' + str(os.path.getsize(dir + '/' + f)) + '\n')

report.write('\n')
report.write('Size of the chunks of the files (in bytes)' + '\n')
report.write('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' + '\n')

fs = open("fs.log",'r');
fn = open("fn.log",'r');
for eachline1, eachline2 in zip(fs, fn):
    chunk_size = float(eachline1)/float(eachline2[48:51])
    report.write(eachline2[:47] + ' ' + "%.2f" % chunk_size + '\n')

report.write('\n')
report.write('Sync starting time' + '\n')
report.write('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' + '\n')

pre_st = open("pre_st.log", 'r')
st = open("st.log", 'w')
lineList = pre_st.readlines()
lineList.sort()
for line in lineList:
    st.write(line)
    report.write(line)
report.write('\n')
pre_st.close()

report.write('Sync ending time' + '\n')
report.write('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' + '\n')

pre_et = open("pre_et.log", 'r')
et = open("et.log", 'w')
lineList = pre_et.readlines()
lineList.sort()
for line in lineList:
    et.write(line)
    report.write(line)
report.write('\n')      
pre_et.close()

report.write('Time required for syncing (in seconds)' + '\n')
report.write('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' + '\n')

st = open("st.log",'r');
et = open("et.log",'r');
tt = open("tt.log",'w');
for eachline1, eachline2 in zip(st, et):
        if eachline1[:47] == eachline2[:47]:
            s_t=datetime.strptime(eachline1[48:60], "%H:%M:%S.%f")
            e_t=datetime.strptime(eachline2[48:60], "%H:%M:%S.%f")
            diff=e_t-s_t
            tt.write(str(diff.seconds) + '\n')
            report.write(eachline1[:47] + ' ' + str(diff.seconds) + '\n')

report.write('\n')
report.write('Average syncing speed (in KBPS)' + '\n')
report.write('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' + '\n')

fs = open("fs.log",'r');
tt = open("tt.log",'r');
ts = open("ts.log",'w');
for eachline1, eachline2 in zip(fs, tt):
    kbps = float(eachline1)/float(eachline2)/1024
    ts.write("%.2f" % kbps + '\n')
    report.write("%.2f" % kbps + '\n')

report.write('\n')  
report.write('Some statistics regarding syncing speed' + '\n')
report.write('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' + '\n')

ts = open("ts.log",'r');
sum=0
sumsq=0
for eachline in ts:
    sum=sum+float(eachline)
    sumsq=sumsq+float(eachline)*float(eachline)

mean=sum/i
sd=math.sqrt((sumsq/i)-mean*mean)
report.write("Mean: %.3f" % mean + '\n')
report.write("SD: %.3f" % sd)

fs.close()
fn.close()
st.close()
et.close()
tt.close()
ts.close()
os.remove("pre_st.log")
os.remove("pre_et.log")
os.remove("fs.log")
os.remove("fn.log")
os.remove("st.log")
os.remove("et.log")
os.remove("tt.log")
os.remove("ts.log")

raw_input("\nThe log is analysed & the report is stored in report.log.")
raw_input("\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Output is:

```
Name of the files & corresponding no of chunks
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out 801
AUD_30_3822029472_1442025768_20140923053708.out 801
AUD_59_3579916998_7069213690_20130110135656.out 801
AUD_61_3949868720_1329085991_20140304201127.out 801
AUD_69_4708795896_5381639942_20151207235120.out 801
AUD_84_7923993614_7033456750_20140701194619.out 801
AUD_91_1017552763_1580925238_20150504230140.out 801
IMG_08_1835175262_0348482033_20151030013511.out 801
IMG_58_1221213139_0317767252_20140224102055.out 801
IMG_85_5493890382_1220034673_20150124103303.out 801
TXT_39_6233284218_9061455668_20140311141700.out 801
TXT_44_0723897111_3504488735_20130221025651.out 801
TXT_44_6371464119_5534251140_20130627035614.out 801
TXT_46_4298501313_8016306909_20130904123345.out 801
TXT_58_8366996486_3506161308_20131016091717.out 801
TXT_62_4001716298_7792106100_20130219205926.out 801
VID_05_6236865421_4023459915_20141130065941.out 801
VID_27_7325125621_7609682883_20151006221708.out 801
VID_33_6052974216_0442981490_20130712161750.out 801
VID_53_4632285308_2718774440_20140227033833.out 801

Total no of files
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
20

Size of the files (in bytes)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out 52435165
AUD_30_3822029472_1442025768_20140923053708.out 52435165
AUD_59_3579916998_7069213690_20130110135656.out 52435165
AUD_61_3949868720_1329085991_20140304201127.out 52435165
AUD_69_4708795896_5381639942_20151207235120.out 52435165
AUD_84_7923993614_7033456750_20140701194619.out 52435165
AUD_91_1017552763_1580925238_20150504230140.out 52435165
IMG_08_1835175262_0348482033_20151030013511.out 52435165
IMG_58_1221213139_0317767252_20140224102055.out 52435165
IMG_85_5493890382_1220034673_20150124103303.out 52435165
TXT_39_6233284218_9061455668_20140311141700.out 52435165
TXT_44_0723897111_3504488735_20130221025651.out 52435165
TXT_44_6371464119_5534251140_20130627035614.out 52435165
TXT_46_4298501313_8016306909_20130904123345.out 52435165
TXT_58_8366996486_3506161308_20131016091717.out 52435165
TXT_62_4001716298_7792106100_20130219205926.out 52435165
VID_05_6236865421_4023459915_20141130065941.out 52435165
VID_27_7325125621_7609682883_20151006221708.out 52435165
VID_33_6052974216_0442981490_20130712161750.out 52435165
VID_53_4632285308_2718774440_20140227033833.out 52435165

Size of the chunks of the files (in bytes)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out 65462.13
AUD_30_3822029472_1442025768_20140923053708.out 65462.13
AUD_59_3579916998_7069213690_20130110135656.out 65462.13
AUD_61_3949868720_1329085991_20140304201127.out 65462.13
AUD_69_4708795896_5381639942_20151207235120.out 65462.13
AUD_84_7923993614_7033456750_20140701194619.out 65462.13
AUD_91_1017552763_1580925238_20150504230140.out 65462.13
IMG_08_1835175262_0348482033_20151030013511.out 65462.13
IMG_58_1221213139_0317767252_20140224102055.out 65462.13
IMG_85_5493890382_1220034673_20150124103303.out 65462.13
TXT_39_6233284218_9061455668_20140311141700.out 65462.13
TXT_44_0723897111_3504488735_20130221025651.out 65462.13
TXT_44_6371464119_5534251140_20130627035614.out 65462.13
TXT_46_4298501313_8016306909_20130904123345.out 65462.13
TXT_58_8366996486_3506161308_20131016091717.out 65462.13
TXT_62_4001716298_7792106100_20130219205926.out 65462.13
VID_05_6236865421_4023459915_20141130065941.out 65462.13
VID_27_7325125621_7609682883_20151006221708.out 65462.13
VID_33_6052974216_0442981490_20130712161750.out 65462.13
VID_53_4632285308_2718774440_20140227033833.out 65462.13

Sync starting time
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out 12:10:43.117
AUD_30_3822029472_1442025768_20140923053708.out 12:11:03.951
AUD_59_3579916998_7069213690_20130110135656.out 12:12:10.933
AUD_61_3949868720_1329085991_20140304201127.out 12:12:34.120
AUD_69_4708795896_5381639942_20151207235120.out 12:12:56.050
AUD_84_7923993614_7033456750_20140701194619.out 12:13:20.291
AUD_91_1017552763_1580925238_20150504230140.out 12:13:41.095
IMG_08_1835175262_0348482033_20151030013511.out 12:14:12.536
IMG_58_1221213139_0317767252_20140224102055.out 12:14:22.594
IMG_85_5493890382_1220034673_20150124103303.out 12:14:22.619
TXT_39_6233284218_9061455668_20140311141700.out 12:14:22.644
TXT_44_0723897111_3504488735_20130221025651.out 12:14:22.670
TXT_44_6371464119_5534251140_20130627035614.out 12:14:22.695
TXT_46_4298501313_8016306909_20130904123345.out 12:14:22.720
TXT_58_8366996486_3506161308_20131016091717.out 12:14:22.745
TXT_62_4001716298_7792106100_20130219205926.out 12:14:22.770
VID_05_6236865421_4023459915_20141130065941.out 12:14:22.795
VID_27_7325125621_7609682883_20151006221708.out 12:18:16.565
VID_33_6052974216_0442981490_20130712161750.out 12:18:36.599
VID_53_4632285308_2718774440_20140227033833.out 12:18:56.971

Sync ending time
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out 12:11:03.951
AUD_30_3822029472_1442025768_20140923053708.out 12:12:10.933
AUD_59_3579916998_7069213690_20130110135656.out 12:12:34.120
AUD_61_3949868720_1329085991_20140304201127.out 12:12:56.050
AUD_69_4708795896_5381639942_20151207235120.out 12:13:20.291
AUD_84_7923993614_7033456750_20140701194619.out 12:13:41.095
AUD_91_1017552763_1580925238_20150504230140.out 12:15:45.028
IMG_08_1835175262_0348482033_20151030013511.out 12:14:46.928
IMG_58_1221213139_0317767252_20140224102055.out 12:15:08.705
IMG_85_5493890382_1220034673_20150124103303.out 12:15:30.388
TXT_39_6233284218_9061455668_20140311141700.out 12:16:06.094
TXT_44_0723897111_3504488735_20130221025651.out 12:16:27.998
TXT_44_6371464119_5534251140_20130627035614.out 12:16:48.881
TXT_46_4298501313_8016306909_20130904123345.out 12:17:09.655
TXT_58_8366996486_3506161308_20131016091717.out 12:17:34.825
TXT_62_4001716298_7792106100_20130219205926.out 12:17:56.456
VID_05_6236865421_4023459915_20141130065941.out 12:18:16.565
VID_27_7325125621_7609682883_20151006221708.out 12:18:36.599
VID_33_6052974216_0442981490_20130712161750.out 12:18:56.972
VID_53_4632285308_2718774440_20140227033833.out 12:19:19.166

Time required for syncing (in seconds)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AUD_16_1122404893_7156305832_20131013215115.out 20
AUD_30_3822029472_1442025768_20140923053708.out 66
AUD_59_3579916998_7069213690_20130110135656.out 23
AUD_61_3949868720_1329085991_20140304201127.out 21
AUD_69_4708795896_5381639942_20151207235120.out 24
AUD_84_7923993614_7033456750_20140701194619.out 20
AUD_91_1017552763_1580925238_20150504230140.out 123
IMG_08_1835175262_0348482033_20151030013511.out 34
IMG_58_1221213139_0317767252_20140224102055.out 46
IMG_85_5493890382_1220034673_20150124103303.out 67
TXT_39_6233284218_9061455668_20140311141700.out 103
TXT_44_0723897111_3504488735_20130221025651.out 125
TXT_44_6371464119_5534251140_20130627035614.out 146
TXT_46_4298501313_8016306909_20130904123345.out 166
TXT_58_8366996486_3506161308_20131016091717.out 192
TXT_62_4001716298_7792106100_20130219205926.out 213
VID_05_6236865421_4023459915_20141130065941.out 233
VID_27_7325125621_7609682883_20151006221708.out 20
VID_33_6052974216_0442981490_20130712161750.out 20
VID_53_4632285308_2718774440_20140227033833.out 22

Average syncing speed (in KBPS)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2560.31
775.85
2226.36
2438.39
2133.59
2560.31
416.31
1506.07
1113.18
764.27
497.15
409.65
350.73
308.47
266.70
240.40
219.77
2560.31
2560.31
2327.56

Some statistics regarding syncing speed
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Mean: 1311.785
SD: 957.979
```

I know its nothing near to the ideal approach but for now I can manage with this. But I'm looking forward to improve it. Thanks for the helps!